# How can you find the degrees of a curved line's corners by graphing a vertical and horizontal line?

Tags: geometry, curves, angle

Sorry if my title appears subjective I am sure there is a more technical term for what I am asking. Maybe the image will explain my question better.

[image: red axes of a coordinate system with a black curve intersecting both axes. The angles of intersection are marked with question marks]

Comment: draw the tangents?

Comment: Do you know calculus?

Comment: Are the red lines a coordinate system?

Comment: No, I don't know calculus that well except the chain rule, what part of calculus should I look into? Also the red lines can be the coordinate system. My original problem is trying to cluster multiple similar curves into a group. I broke down my problem to tinier steps and to group curves I need to know how to id their directions, that's why I asked this question. As you can see my math knowledge is limited.

Comment: Do you know the equation of the curve? Do you know the coordinates of the intersection between the two orthogonal lines?

Comment: I would say no to the equation of the curve but yes to the intersecting coordinates of the 2 orthogonal lines. The curves will be completely random because they will actually be my pencil strokes. I just want an estimation of the direction of the curves by measuring their "outer corner angles"? So I can then repeat the process and depends on the angle I can group or cluster similar strokes together. I guess I can take the slope of the curve and compare that as well which is the partial derivative is that correct?

Comment: Okay I think I have a basic idea now with all the hints. I am going to pick 3 different points on my curve and find the tangent line for those points wrt the curve itself then sum and average them to get a result. I can then do this for multiple curves and set some logic rules to group them together. This is probably the easiest way.